# How to print variable's value as literal string

Tags: bash, variables, literals

Not sure if the title is precise. Let's say I have a variable with a string:

```
var=C:\Windows\file.exe
```

And I'd like to print it's value as if it were a literal string, i.e. I want to see this on the screen:

```
C:\Windows\file.exe
```

But, of course, the usual ways to print a variable don't do that:

```
echo $var
C:Windowsfile.exe
echo "$var"
C:Windowsfile.exe
echo '$var'
$var
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Again, `bash` or `batch` ?

Comment: Bash, don't mind the example, it's just about the usage of backslashes.

Comment: Do you know what back slash character means?

Comment: under which OS ? cygwin ? try `echo -E "${var}"`

Comment: linux/unix, not windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the backslashes are being operated on by shell at definition time, not when you are evaluating the variable later. You need to quote the declaration i.e. use any shell escaping mechanism to escape the `\`s.

**Here is what you are doing:**

```
$ var=C:\Windows\file.exe

$ echo "$var"
C:Windowsfile.exe
```

**Here is what you need:**

```
$ var='C:\Windows\file.exe'

$ echo "$var"
C:\Windows\file.exe
```

Comment: Wow, I actually know that and I thought I tried quoting the literal. Apparently not. Thanks either way.

Comment: Note the specific use of single quotes. Inside a double-quoted string, there are three escape sequences that are processed: `\\``, `\$`, and \\. (The first to allow literal backquotes without starting a command substitution, the second to allow a literal `$` without starting a parameter expansion, and the last so you can specify a literal backslash without escaping a following backtick or dollar sign.)